# Qiskit: total number of parameters after composing parametrized circuits

Tags: programming, qiskit

I'm trying to use the `.compose()` method to join two parametrized circuits, specifically `TwoLocal` instances from the `qiskit.circuit.library`.

While I would expect that `.num_parameters_settable()` would be the sum of the parameters in each circuit, the final circuit will have only as many settable parameters as only one of them.

Version: qiskit-0.26.2

Thank you very much for your help!

My code is:

```
from qiskit.circuit.library import TwoLocal
import numpy as np

    rot = TwoLocal(
        int(np.sum(num_qubits)),
        "ry",
        [],
        reps=1,
        skip_final_rotation_layer=True,
        parameter_prefix="p",
    )

    var = TwoLocal(
            int(np.sum(num_qubits)),
            "ry",
            "cx",
            entanglement="linear",
            reps=1,
            skip_final_rotation_layer=True,
        )
    rot.num_parameters_settable()
    >> 2
    rot.compose(var, inplace=True)
    rot.num_parameters_settable()
    >> 2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the [documentation for TwoLocal](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stable/0.25/stubs/qiskit.circuit.library.TwoLocal.html), you can see that `.num_parameters_settable` refers to the number of parameters originally available in the circuit.

[image: Documentation for num_parameters_settable]

However, `.num_parameters` will give you what you are looking for. I tried it with your code setting `num_qubits=2` and it indeed works as you want. This property is defined as:

[image]

Meaning that it actually updates when an action like `.compose()` is made on the circuit.